# "File was not uploaded" magento error even file is uploaded to particular folder

Tags: magento, file-upload

I am making an application in which i am uploading file from my custom tab as follows

[image]

i created a observer for event called `catalog_product_save_after`. In the particular function, i am uploading those files to catalog/product folder and its get uploaded to those folder without any error.

But when i am trying to assign those images to that particular product, i got the following error.
`File was not uploaded` at file `E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\File\Uploader.php on line 152`

If i check `system.log` then i see the `2012-08-24T11:33:15+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 3645` this error.

My observer function is as follows

```
public function Savedata($observer)
    {
        $params     =   Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

        $product    =   $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        $product_id =   $product->getId();


        $filesData  =   array();


        $keysData   =   array_keys($_FILES);


        foreach($keysData as $keys)
        {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader("$keys");
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'tiff'));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS  . "catalog" . DS . "product";

            if(!is_dir($path))
            {
                mkdir($path);
            }

            $extension  =   pathinfo($_FILES["$keys"]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            $date = new DateTime();

            $file_name                  =   $keys . "_" . $product_id . "." . $extension;

            $_FILES["$keys"]['name']    =   $file_name;

            $uploader->save($path, $_FILES["$keys"]['name']);
            $filesData[]    =   $path .DS. $_FILES["$keys"]['name'];
        }

        print_r($filesData);
        ///till this works file.. when i add following code, program dies. 

        try 
        {
            $productData = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

            print_r($productData->getData());


            foreach($filesData as $file)
            {
                $productData->addImageToMediaGallery($file, "image" ,false, false);
            }
            $productData->save();

            $productData = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

            print_r($productData->getData());
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage() . "||" . $e->getCode() . "||" . $e->getFile() . "||" . $e->getLine();
        }


        exit();
    }
```

any suggestion where i am going wrong? why this error occur?

i am using magento 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're going to update your catalog/product object when you're saving it.

You are using event `catalog_product_save_after`.

Inside the observer, you call:

```
$productData = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
...
$productData->save();
```

$productData is catalog/product object -> you saved it.

You can guess what will happen, it will trigger event `catalog_product_save_after` and so on, looping forever.

I see that you call `$productData->save();` because in this event, the value has been saved and can not be changed.

So instead of using `catalog_product_save_after`, you can use `catalog_product_save_before`.

The same like your code, but remove `$productData->save();` because it will automatically call save.

```
Mage_Core_Model_Abstract

public function save()
{
    /**
     * Direct deleted items to delete method
     */
    if ($this->isDeleted()) {
        return $this->delete();
    }
    if (!$this->_hasModelChanged()) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->_getResource()->beginTransaction();
    $dataCommited = false;
    try {
        $this->_beforeSave();
        if ($this->_dataSaveAllowed) {
            //see this line below, it will call save, so you don't need to call save in your `catalog_product_save_before` (no looping forever)
            $this->_getResource()->save($this);
            $this->_afterSave();
        }
        $this->_getResource()->addCommitCallback(array($this, 'afterCommitCallback'))
            ->commit();
        $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
        $dataCommited = true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getResource()->rollBack();
        $this->_hasDataChanges = true;
        throw $e;
    }
    if ($dataCommited) {
        $this->_afterSaveCommit();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: yes.. i was thinking same.. very good explanation. Thanks a lot.